# Ok to use temp tables and table variable in the same stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one select in my stored procedure that returns 4000 + rows. I was going to make this a temp table to work off the data later in the procedure.

I also have various other selects that only return 100-300 rows. I was going to make these table variables, again to work off later in the procedure.

Is it ok to use temp tables and table variables in the same procedure, or will this cause any performance issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is ok.

As for programming practice, I would prefer one type or the other (and lean toward table variables), if I'm reading a stored procedure.  However, you might have a good reason for using one or the other, such as needing an index on a temp table or using it for a `select into`, then go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you need to look for a full set of options [**sommarskog.se - share_data**](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

Being able to add various indexes to temp tables is a particularly reason I'll sometimes choose temporary tables.

To avoid hitting temp db continuously, and if indexes are not required, then I'll use table variables.

Quite often now I use lots of `CTE`s that work together and avoid using any sort of materialized tables.

Classic answer - *"it depends!"*

Comment: I'll second the classic answer.  Try both temp tables and table variables and see which performs better for your use case.  

I'll also add be careful with CTEs.  They can lead to bad performance as their results are not cached and so the full CTE query can end up being executed again and again if it is being used in a join.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many factors here that we don't know, such as your company's resources, your time-constraints, etc.

Generally speaking, it is fine to use temp tables for this purpose. And 100-300 rows(mentioned in the selects) - that's peanuts. No worries.